# java selenium xpath to get String value

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

I am wondering how to get the value 14.84 for "purhaseTotal"? The value 14.84 can change based on item price so that is not constant. Basically I want to capture that order total which is expressed in value= when I see that pruchaseTotal

```
<span id="spc-form-inputs">

    <input type="hidden" name="purchaseTotal" value="14.84">
    <input type="hidden" name="purchaseTotalCurrency" value="USD">

    <input type="hidden" value="">

        </span>
```

//span//input ... getText()?
I can use some help here. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.getAttribute`.

`By.xpath`:

```
String value = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@id='spc-form-inputs']//input[@name='purchaseTotal']")).getAttribute("value");
```

`By.name`:

```
String value = driver.findElement(By.name("purchaseTotal")).getAttribute("value");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the `input` tag by `attribute=name`.

```
//span[@id='spc-form-inputs']/input[@name='purchaseTotal']/@value
```